# Get directory of Current active file when developing a VSCode extension

Tags: javascript, typescript, vscode-extensions

I am developing a VSCode extension to generate templates.

However, I cannot figure out how to get the location of the VSCode file that I am currently editing.

When I search for this question, most answers say to do something like `vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.uri.fsPath` - however - this gets you the directory for the target VS code window (the Extension Development Host window) - which is not what I want

I want to get the directory of the VS code extension file I am editing (such as the extension.ts file).

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you mean the extension's path, look at `context.extensionPath` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean the extension's path:

`context.extensionPath`

For `extension.ts` try something like:

`context.asAbsolutePath("extension.ts")`  // if at top level

If you don't know the directory structure of the file you are interested in, like `src/otherDirectory/otherSubDirectory`, I think you will have to search/walk for it with `fs` commands starting from the `extensionPath`.  See https://dustinpfister.github.io/2018/07/20/nodejs-ways-to-walk-a-file-system/ for example.

Comment: Excellent - this worked for me - thanks so much! :)